# Android emulator hardware keyboard [Esc] key

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

After upgrading Android Studio from 1.5 to 2.0, the emulator, now version 25.1.1, on which I had configured an emulated hardware keyboard, stopped recognising the [Esc] key as an equivalent to the [Back] button.

How can I restore this useful key mapping?

Note: I have not done anything custom, either in the emulator setup or in the upgrade process.

Occurs both on OS X and Linux.

I do realise the original [Esc] mapping has been "reassigned", to [Command/Apple] + [Backspace] on Macs and [Ctrl] + [Backspace] on Linux for example, yet I'd like to remap it as I use that shortcut already for something else and it forces me to rewrite my "send keys to emulator" testing loop.

Answer (score 3):

Seems that things have changed with new emulator with Android Studio 2.
Earlier ESC/Escape was working as 'back' now it's ctrl + backspace.

New list of keyboard shortcuts:
http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html

More popular:

- back = ctrl + backspace
- rotate = ctrl + arrow left/right
- home = ctrl + h